# numpy meshgrid operations problems

Tags: python, numpy

```
Y, X = np.mgrid[-3:-3:10j, -3:3:10j]
```

I've noticed that when applying certain operations on meshgrids like the one above I get an error because the operations may not be compatible with numpy. Sometimes there might be a numpy function alternative for sin, cos but not for all function like the quad function in scipy.integrate.

How do I get around this problem? I need to apply operations on the entire meshgrids.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say that you need to apply `quad` to every point in a `meshgrid`. `quad` requires a function to be integrated, and bounds for the definite integral. There is `integrate.nquad` which accepts a multivariate function, and a structure called `ranges` that supplies the limits of integration for each coordinate axis. But it's not clear what you are trying to compute from your question.

Comment: Hi. I actually didn't give my real example because the code is too long but say for example that I have a function called MATHOPERATION(x,y) which takes two numbers, x and y, and outputs another number. Where x and y are numbers in X and Y that occupy the same position in the meshgrid. So the the output for MATHOPERATION(X,Y) would be a meshgrid of the same size as X and Y.

Comment: When those operations are not built directly on top of ndarrays, or otherwise built in C code or with a tool like Numba or Cython, then there is no way to "vectorize" them to operate on the contiguous memory stored in the meshgrid arrays. Your best bet is to just write a for-loop over i and j (rows, columns), call your function, and write its result into some pre-allocated 2-D array. The repeated function calling will be slow, and if you profile it and it's too slow, you will need to use something like numba, or code it in C yourself.

Comment: Here are two links that may help: < http://csl.name/C-functions-from-Python/ > and < http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/jakevdp.github.io/downloads/notebooks/NumbaCython.ipynb >. Becoming proficient at doing this for yourself is part of the responsibility of Python. Python gives you excellent flexibility and insane ability to do run-time introspection, but the price is that basic data structures are only contiguous at the pointer level, not at the actual memory locations. And for custom code, it's your job to work with low-level numpy-like implementations to overcome that when you must.

Comment: I elaborated some in an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question (with the follow-on comment) can be taken at least two different ways:

1. You have a function of multiple arguments, and you would like to be able to call that function in a manner that is syntactically similar to the broadcasted calls supported natively by numpy. Performance is not the issue, just the calling syntax of the function.
2. You have a function of multiple arguments that is to be evaluated on a sequence of numpy arrays, but the function is not implemented in such a manner that it can exploit the contiguous memory layout of numpy arrays. Performance is the issue; you would be happy to loop over the numpy arrays and call your function in a boring, plain old for-loop style, except that doing so is too slow.

For item 1. there is a convenience function provided by numpy called `vectorize` which takes a regular callable and returns a callable that can be called with numpy arrays as the arguments and will obey numpy's broadcasting rules.

Consider this contrived example:

```
def my_func(x, y):
    return x + 2*y
```

Now suppose I need to evaluate this function everywhere in a 2-D grid. Here is the plain old boring way:

```
Y, X  =  np.mgrid[0:10:1, 0:10:1]
Z = np.zeros_like(Y)

for i in range(Y.shape[0]):
    for j in range(Y.shape[1]):
        Z[i,j] = my_func(X[i,j], Y[i,j])
```

If we had a few different functions like `my_func`, it might be nice to generalize this process into a function that "mapped" a given function over the 2-D arrays.

```
import itertools
def array_map(some_func, *arg_arrays):
    output = np.zeros_like(arg_arrays[0])
    coordinates = itertools.imap(range, output.shape)
    for coord in itertools.product(coordinates):
        args = [arg_array[coord] for arg_array in arg_arrays]
        output[coord] = some_func(*args)
    return output
```

Now we can see that `array_map(my_func, X, Y)` acts just like the nested for-loop:

```
In [451]: array_map(my_func, X, Y)
Out[451]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])
```

Now, wouldn't it be nice if we could call `array_map(my_func)` and leave off the extra array arguments? Instead just getting back a new function that was just waiting to do the required for-loops.

We can do this with `functools.partial` -- so we can write a handy little vectorizer like this:

```
import functools
def vectorizer(regular_function):
    awesome_function = functools.partial(array_map, regular_function)
    return awesome_function
```

and testing it out:

```
In [453]: my_awesome_func = vectorizer(my_func)

In [454]: my_awesome_func(X, Y)
Out[454]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])
```

Now `my_awesome_func` behaves as if you are able to call it directly on top of ndarrays!

I've overlooked many extra little performance details, bounds checking, etc., while making this toy version called `vectorizer` ... but luckily in numpy there is `vectorize` which already does just this!

```
In [455]: my_vectorize_func = np.vectorize(my_func)

In [456]: my_vectorize_func(X, Y)
Out[456]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])
```

Once again, as stressed in my earlier comments to the OP and in the documentation for `vectorize` -- this **is not** a speed optimization. In fact, the extra function calling overhead will be slower in some cases than just writing a for-loop directly. But, for cases when speed is not a problem, this method does allow you to make your custom functions adhere to the same calling conventions as numpy -- which can improve the uniformity of your library's interface and make the code more consistent and more readable.

A whole lot of other stuff has already been written about item 2. If your problem is that you need to optimize your functions to leverage contiguous blocks of memory and by-passing repeated dynamic type checking (the main features that numpy arrays add to Python lists) then here are a few links you may find helpful:

1. < http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html >
2. < http://csl.name/C-functions-from-Python/ >
3. < https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/05/09/why-python-is-slow >
4. < nbviewer.ipython.org/url/jakevdp.github.io/downloads/notebooks/NumbaCython.ipynb >

Comment: Hi prpl. I tried the forloop trick but it didn't work for a particular function I was using. I've made a new question about it on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091037/numpy-iterating-calculations-in-a-meshgrid

Comment: `OverflowError` occurs when a math operation results in a value too large to be represented. Judging by the name `Emag` I'm guessing this is some electromagnetic grid calculation -- and so maybe if your function involves poles, you are trying to calculate a value too close to a pole and getting numerical overflow. Either way, this is not related to the problem of calculating on a grid, but rather instead an error with your use of math operations inside of the definition of `Emag`.