# Numpy Meshgrids in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I've noticed that when applying certain operations on meshgrids like the one below I get an error because the operations may not be compatible with numpy. Sometimes there might be a numpy function alternative for sin, cos but not for all functions like functions in scipy.

Say, I have a function called MATHOPERATION(x,y) which takes two numbers, x and y, and outputs another number. Where x and y are numbers in X and Y that occupy the same position in the meshgrid. So the the output for MATHOPERATION(X,Y) would be a meshgrid of the same size as X and Y

So my question is how do I get around this problem when the function MATHOPERATION isn't compatible with numpy?

Comment: Is this the same as your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082191/numpy-meshgrid-operations-problems)?  If so, please edit any new explanations into the original question instead of asking a separate duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may want to use

```
import numpy as np
map(MATHOPERATION , np.ravel(X) , np.ravel(Y))
```

which should make your meshgrid a sequence-like object.