# Numpy Iterating calculations in a meshgrid

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

Recently, by the kind response of a stackoverflow member, I learnt how to perform operations on meshgrids with functions that weren't contiguous with with numpy using a for-loop trick to iterate over each of the elements in the grid. I found that it worked on most occasions however, below, for some reason it seems to be failing:
Emag is a long function that I created.

```
import numpy as np
X, Y  =  np.mgrid[0.1:0.15:3j, 0.1:0.15:3j]
Z = np.zeros_like(Y)                    
po = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
phio = np.arctan2(Y,X)
print po
print phio

for i in range(po.shape[0]):                     
    for j in range(po.shape[1]):
        print po[i,j]
        print phio[i,j]
        Z[i,j] = Emag(po[i,j], phio[i,j], 0)
        print Z[i,j]
```

Below is the response

```
%run C:/Users/Nigel/Desktop/Nigel07112014.py
[[ 0.14142136  0.16007811  0.18027756]         <--- po
 [ 0.16007811  0.1767767   0.19525624]
 [ 0.18027756  0.19525624  0.21213203]]
[[ 0.78539816  0.89605538  0.98279372]         <--- phio
 [ 0.67474094  0.78539816  0.87605805]
 [ 0.5880026   0.69473828  0.78539816]]
0.141421356237   <--- po[0,0]
0.785398163397   <--- phio[0,0]
732.46186213     <--- Z[0,0]
0.160078105936   <--- po[0,1]
0.896055384571   <--- phio[0,1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
```

It seems that for the second element of the meshgrid, the computer has trouble producing an output for Z. However, when I execute Emag for the second elements of po and phio separately - it works just fine (see below):

```
Emag(0.160078105936, 0.896055384571, 0)
> 589.541876301
```

which should be the second element of the Z meshgrid.

So where's it going wrong? *I'll paste the much longer error message if requested*

Full error message below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195             else:
    196                 filename = fname
--> 197             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198     else:
    199         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\Nigel07112014.py in <module>()
    220         print po[i,j]
    221         print phio[i,j]
--> 222         Z[i,j] = Emag(po[i,j], phio[i,j], 0)
    223         print Z[i,j]
    224 

C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\Nigel07112014.py in Emag(p, phi, z)
    149 def Emag(p, phi, z):
    150     if z >=0:
--> 151         VE1p = (p * (z-z0) * ((MuZ)/(4 * pi * Eps0 * Eps1)) * exp(j * k1 * R0 / (R0**3)) * ((3/(R0**2))- (3 * j * k1 / R0)-(k1**2)) ) - ( j * ((MuZ)/(4 * pi * Eps0 * Eps1)) * INTEGRATEZI( lambda kp: J1(kp * p) * A1(kp) * kp * k1z(kp) * (exp(1j * k1z(kp) * (z + z0))) ) )
    152 
    153         VE1phi = 0

OverflowError: math range error
```

Comment: As a quick debugging hint, modify `Emag` to print its arguments.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried your code with a mock `Emag` and it ran flawlessly... maybe you have to post the full traceback

Comment: Hi gboffi. I've added the full error message - bear in mind that that Emag does work for the individual values - just not when they're in the meshgrid

Comment: You keep saying that `Emag` works for the individual values, but you haven't proven that anywhere (Hint - 0.160078105936 and 0.896055384571 are not the *exact* values passed into the function, just a representation of them). Post the shortest, complete example which reproduces the error, otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: You have a `j` in the failing expression that receives the wrong value from the outer context.  When you execute the function from another not from the loop, G.d knows which `j` is used and your value is computed... I see that in other instances you have `1j` that in python is the imaginary unit, and makes perfect sense if you're computing angles, phases etc, is it possible that...

Comment: Sorry Talonmies, I'm a bit confused by what you mean. Are you suggesting that because 0.160078105936 and 0.896055384571 are rounded values they will produce very different results? This is the only example that I am facing where I am receiving this error.

Comment: Hi @gboffi I defined j=1j at the start of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `exp( j ...` in your `Emag` to `exp( 1j ...` if you're dealing with exponentials of imaginary argument.  When it's executed inside the loop `j` can receive *bad* values from `j` the index of the loop.

Should I be right with respect to imaginary arguments, I would also triple check the results of your `Emag` function.

Comment: Hi.At the start of the code I wrote j=1j (not seen above)

Comment: It also doesn't explain - I think - why when entering the values separately it works fine.

Comment: Even if you tried to set `j=1j`, if you later loop with a variable named `j`, it will destructively change that value over and over. You won't be able to guarantee that it is the complex unit later on. Really, you need to be much more careful with your use of complex numbers in the code.

Comment: I recommend that you use a literal `1j` where you need the imaginary unit. It's just one character longer and you are no more at risk that the value of `j` is polluted by, let's say a loop in which you inadvertently use `j` as a counter.

Comment: Thanks gboffi. Thanks prpl.